# In python how to generate date in utc/gmt?

Tags: python

I am using dateutil.parser to generate a random date, it seem to be in my local timezone, how do I generate it in UTC/GMT?

```
from dateutil import parser
new_date = str(random.randint(1,27))+"/"+str(random.randint(1,12))+"/"+str(random.randint(2001,2020)) #d/m/y
targetdate = parser.parse(new_date, dayfirst=True)
```

Comment: dates don't have a timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use `datetime` directly, rather than trying to parse a string you generate.

```py
import datetime
import random

def generate_random_date(from=datetime.datetime(month=1, day=1, year=2001),
                         to=datetime.datetime(month=1, day=1, year=2021)):
    from_t, to_t = from.timestamp(), to.timestamp()
    gen = random.randint(int(from_t), int(to_t))
    return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(gen).date()
```

Comment: Works really well, only change I would recommend is that "from" is a keyword and I changed it to "from_" to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
utc_current_datetime = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("UTC"))
print(utc_current_datetime)
```

this returns the time in UTC which prints `2021-05-03 03:38:45.652857+00:00`

alternatively you can use the time module like so:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
utc_current_datetime = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
print(utc_current_datetime)
```

also UTC which prints `2021-05-03 03:38:45.652857+00:00`

if you just want the date from this, you can use

```
utc_current_datetime.date()
```

The time module has many other functions that can help you. Take a look at the [time documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) and [DateTime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) for more information